Need help identifying a (possibly) 1984 Winter Olympics bicycle
My wife and I recently bought a house and found an old bicycle in the attic. I have tried identifying it, but came up short.
There's a small sticker on the front of the frame with a 2x2 grid containing: the Mitsubishi logo (top left), the 1984 Winter Olympics logo (top right), the text "Official Car Supplier" (bottom left), "Sarajevo 1984" (bottom right), and something that looks like "JOC SS-4 B2JO" (bottom right, corner).
This makes me think it's some sort of a commemorative bicycle made during the 1984 (Winter!) Olympics, but I can't find any mention of bicycles of any kind during those Olympics. The only thing related to Mitsubishi and the 1984 Olympics I managed to find was an article talking about a restored 1984 Olympics Mitsubishi van - no bicycles.
Other than the sticker, I found no potentially identifying markings on the bicycle, but I could add a few more photos if someone could tell me what to look for and where.
What is this bicycle, and would a collector or some kind of a museum want it? Or is it just scrap metal given its state?


A closeup of the sticker:





Great job on the pictures! My wife and my basement will testify that I will save the lowliest of bicycles. My best guess is that this bike is not collectable. Fixing it up would be an expensive labor of love. You might find someone who will take it off your hands for free.

Thanks! I'll be honest and admit I didn't see your guide for "ID my bike" questions until now, but I'm glad I didn't miss anything crucial. I'll probably make my wife a bit happier and someone else's wife a bit less happy by placing an ad and giving the bike away ASAP. :) And if it turns out nobody wants/needs it, there's always the local scrapyard.

According to https://olympics.com/en/sports/winter-olympics#sarajevo-1984 there are no cycling events at Sarajevo in 1984.  So it can't be an event bike.   There is a small chance it was transport at the event, but more likely its just a sticker that ended up on the frame.
You can test if the sticker is under the clearcoat of the paint by feeling for an edge with a fingernail.  If you can find a definite lip, the sticker is on top of the paint, and if there is a smooth transition, the sticker is under the clearcoat and was added during manufacture.
The components visible pre-date Shimano's dominance.  I see a Huret rear derailleur.  Also the rim brakes are nice center-pull or perhaps U brakes.
I see every part needed in your photos somewhere, including the saddle and seat post. You could simply assemble the bike, clean it and see how it goes.   There's a good chance the brake pads are hardened and the tyres may not hold air, but its been stored out of the sun so anything's possible.
It looks like a quality well-made 80's bike, but nothing exceptional.  If you want to ride it, then it just needs effort.   If you want to pass it on, either list on your local auction site and its worth however much it sells for, or donate it to your local bike coop/fixup group.   We can't reasonably put valuations out, sorry.

Sorry, it seems my question title was a bit misleading - I didn't expect it to be an event bicycle, I was leaning more to the "commemorative/transport/misc" side.
I went and checked the sticker, and the edges are definitely noticable, so it was most likely added post production, as you say. I highly doubt it just "ended up" on the frame because of how neatly it's placed, but I might be wrong.  (1/2)

I wasn't intent on riding it since I already have a bicycle and don't see much point in riding a bike that's at least 10 years older than me.
I also don't possess the  skills or the tools to properly disassemble, clean, and reassemble the bicycle so I was hoping to just identify it, then see if I can donate it to someone who would appreciate it. If that fails, I'll probably just trash it.
All in all, thanks for the answer, I appreciate the effort. Does this stack have a rule of waiting 24 hours before accepting an answer? (2/2)

@weenko don't trash it please - either donate it or just list it on an auction site for $1 and it will go.   I drive a CAR that's older than me, an old bike is fine to ride.
